# PHP array keys values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key, array-key

I have an **array** like this

```
$data = array(
    "some"   => "163",
    "rand"  => "630",
    "om"    => "43",
    "words" => "924",
    "as"    => "4",
    "keys"  => "54"
);
```

How can I get **each set's key** associated **with their values** like this:

```
foreach ($data as $stuff){
  $this->$stuff["key"] = $stuff["value"];
}
```

Comment: Very first code block on the very first Google result for "php foreach" yields exactly what you'd expect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
  echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    // $key and $value variable are available here
    // First iteration values would be: $key = "some" and $value = "163"
}
```